# Styling Jquery-ui tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am playing with the jquery tabs attempting to style them the way I see fit. I attempted to shrink the tabs and added a `height:45px;` to the UI stylesheet as seen below.

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { 
  clear: left; 
  height:45px; 
  width: 100%; 
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important; 
  border-right-width: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
}
```

Yet, instead of shrinking all the tabs it kept one (the last one) unchanged. It can be seen here, the tab labeled Trash [JS-FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/53/). I would like to understand what is going on and how I can fix it. Also, any other coding tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anchor tag inside the `li` is higher than the `li`. If you restrict that height it can work.

```
    .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { height: 30px; }
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/54/)

I just noticed with chrome developer tools that your tabs are overlapping. Only the last one is not overlapped and therefore looks taller than the others.

Comment: I've fixed it slightly another way, by applying `overflow:hidden` to `.accordion li` rule : http://jsfiddle.net/gYfQD/

Comment: @keaukraine if you look close you will see that your solution does not have the border around the tabs, so it may need some additional styling to get the border at the bottom back

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to this. Your solution really looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

First shirink the font size in widget

```
.ui-widget{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:medium}
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing with this height will solve the issue:

> .accordion li > a  {height:30px !important; }